# How to make node view show approved, not latest

Tags: 6, workflows

I've got a client with an old Drupal 6 site that uses workflow and revisions. They want a blog added with related content types and Views. All works except that for the node page itself, it shows the latest revision, even if an earlier one is approved within workflow. The tab says "View Latest." For the already-existing Events content type, it shows the most recently approved revision and the tab says "View." I've looked in workflow config and have compared workflow settings for the two content types and cannot see where this is controlled. I would add that the fact that Views is called Views means that searching on "node view" is almost worthless. Any help in how I can make this old site show the approved version for the node page would be appreciated.